# how to write x squared in latex

Tags: macos, latex

I can't find the answer online, I dont' knwo why

I'm trying to write this:

f(x) = as^2 + 5x - c

but first i get an error:

```
Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
f(x) = ax^
          2 +5x -c
```

I tried adding a dollar sign before the 2 but then just got the same error, but without the equation, I then substituted the $ symbol for a \ and that kind of worked, but I got a full sized 2 with the caret above it, how do you get the small 2 to appear?

Comment: It's not clear to me what app you're using to write LaTeX.  $LaTeX$ in-line needs leading and trailing dollar sign: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52276/inline-equation-in-latex-with-text

Comment: Yes i just found that out,  I wish it was easier to find the answer though

Comment: I'd bet it's in every LaTeX tutorial.  You need to search better.

Comment: @duffymo you need to be a better person.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, that's a super confusing error message, being new to Latex I did not know that the Dollar sign was for,but basically it needs to have a dollar sign at either end of the expression so it seems. Maybe someone else has a more detailed answer.

```
$f(x) = {ax}^2 +5x -c$
```

but the above did work.

Comment: You should put your whole equation in math mode. If you only wrap the last part in `$`-signs, the spacing around the `=` will be wrong. Also the font will look off.

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-10

Comment: Perfect thank you all so much, yes I am very much a beginner and keen to learn. I've edited my answer to reflect your comment also